# how to use Application window? c++

Tags: c++

i have been programming for sometime but all of my programming books have not really showed me how to use the Application window i always use the console window. i was looking at the Application project and i noticed that it has a .cpp file that is the main file but how do work with the window? i have tryed googleing it but i can't find anything really that is usefull, can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many many GUI frameworks, so this question has hundreds of possible answers.

If you are developing on Windows you have the choice of many frameworks including:

- Straight Win32 API
- MFC
- Qt
- WinForms (.Net)
- WPF (.Net)
- Silverlight (.Net)

Depending on what you want to do, and on which platform you will have to select a platform/framework.  Once you select a platform/framework you can get a tutorial or buy a book.